# How to make the text blinking in textview

Tags: java, android, textview

[image]I have a text in `textview` which i need it to be blinking please help me with it.

I tried this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxUd6.png): [How to make the textview blinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294112/how-to-make-the-textview-blinking).

But here the TextView is blinking. I need only the text that is,**"Text1"** to blink.

Comment: use a thread and write the code that makes it "blink", however you imagine that.

Comment: can you show screenshot of what you want to achieve?

Comment: what do you mean by only the `text` to blink? as far as i think its both the same

Comment: Or you could extend TextView and override onDraw(). For a certain period don't call super.onDraw() to not draw the text and for the other periods call it. This way you can get blinking. Don't forget to invalidate the view when changing the state to make the system redraw it and call onDraw() again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this you can to use **`setText()`** to make blink effect in `TextView`

Try below code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#d92804" />
```

Java Code;

```
TextView textView;

textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

testBlink();

    private void testBlink() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int timeToBlink = 1000;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(timeToBlink);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if (textView.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                            textView.setText("Nilesh");
                        } else {
                            textView.setText("");
                        }
                        testBlink();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```