# how to display a flashing textview for duration 5 seconds, then make it invisible?

Tags: android

I want my TextView to appear for 5 seconds so it will be invisible too when the text is displayed flashy.
thanks for your help

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:textColor="#FE9A2E"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />
```

Comment: use animation on textview.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/q/9294112/8089770

Answer (score 1):

Yes it possible using Animation

put this in res/anim folder

alpha_invisible.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fillEnabled="true" >

<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

Java file:

```
int time = 5000; // 5 sec
    Animation animInvisible = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.alpha_invisible);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            textview.startAnimation(animInvisible);
        }
    }, time); // animation invisible textview after 5 sec
```

Comment: If any answer is helpful to you and solve your problem then you can mark as correct : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGNzO.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android's AlphaAnimation to make a View invisible with fade out like animation after some time.

```
AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
animation.setStartOffset(5000);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
tv.startAnimation(animation);
```

Details about AlphaAnimation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html