# ListView Animation not working on first/top 3-4 visible list items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-animation

someone already asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582434/using-a-valueanimator-to-make-a-textview-blink-different-colors?newreg=8c78eb566a744a45a86c30cf12371c04)
But my animation works fine for all other list items except top 3-4 list items that are visible after the listview is created. Basically, i call `NotifyDataSetChanged()` and then based on a condition implemented in `getView()` i start `valueAnimation` on `TextView`. I have no idea why its listview behaving like this.. and What could be the **reason behind** this?

 And how can i handle this **issue without calling `InvalidaeViews()`**.

I have double/triple checked my logic and even asked someone else so lets assume my logic is working fine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have solved it using `[RecyclerView][1]`. 

Now i don't have to `invalidateViews()` or reset the `new MyAdapter(...)`. 

Also another issue i was facing was when i run animation on a textview (in a list item) and on scrolling (listview) your viewHolder recycle/reuses that list item then the animation might be running on textview. So i have to handle this as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and instead of

```
NotifyDataSetChanged()
```

Which didn't change anything, I tried with creating a new adapter, and set it to the listview.

```
userAdapter = new UserCustomAdapter(.....);
userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT : check  these lines too

```
  if (row == null) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
       row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
       holder = new UserHolder();
      } else {
       holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
      }
```

Comment: Thanks. it totally works but is there a way that i could do it using `notifyDataSetChanged()`? And why list view is behaving like this?

Comment: You should check the else case of your "if (row == null)" in your adapter's get View. Accept plz answer if OK ;-)

Comment: ^well it definitely work (so does `invalidateView()`) but this isn't what i am looking for. i need to do it without recreating the list.

Comment: U didn't have to recreate the list, just to update the adpter with the two lines. I although updated the answer.