# Button validation for a quiz app

Tags: java, android

I am working on a quiz app where i am retrieving my data from my model class. Everything is working fine for now. However i want to implement button validation for my answers. For instance, when the user answers a question i want the correct answer(button) to blink green color and the wrong one to blink red color in case the user gets it wrong.

```
/ This file contains questions from QuestionBank
public class QuestionLibrary{
    // array of questions
    private String mQuestions [] = {
// my questions
 };
    // array of multiple choices for each question
    private String mChoices [][] = {
// array of choices appear here
               };
    // array of correct answers - in the same order as array of questions
private String mCorrectAnswers[] = {
            // correct answers appear here
};



    // method returns number of questions
    public int getLength(){
        return mQuestions.length;
    }

    // method returns question from array textQuestions[] based on array index
    public String getQuestion(int a) {
        String question = mQuestions[a];
        return question;
    }

    // method return a single multiple choice item for question based on array index,
    // based on number of multiple choice item in the list - 1, 2, 3 or 4 as an argument
    public String getChoice(int index, int num) {
        String choice0 = mChoices[index][num-1];
        return choice0;
    }

    //  method returns correct answer for the question based on array index
    public String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
        String answer = mCorrectAnswers[a];
        return answer;
    }
}

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();

    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begineer);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstOption);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secondOption);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.thirdOption);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fourthOption);
        updateQuestion(); //update question
        updateQuizNumber(mquizNumber);

    }

    private void updateQuizNumber(int mquizNumber) {
        msingleQuestion.setText("" + mquizNumber+"/"+mQuestionLibrary.getLength());
    }


    private void updateQuestion() {
        // check if we are not outside array bounds for questions
        if(mQuestionNumber<mQuestionLibrary.getLength() ){
            // set the text for new question, and new 4 alternative to answer on four buttons
           mQuestion.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
           button1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 1));
            button2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 2));
            button3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 3));
           button4.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber,4));
            mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
            mQuestionNumber++;
        }
        else {
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuOptions.class);
//            intent.putExtra("score", mScore); // pass the current score to the second screen
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        //all logic for all answers buttons in one method
        Button answer = (Button) view;
        // if the answer is correct, increase the score
        if (answer.getText() == mAnswer){
            Toast.makeText(BegineerActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// i need to validate correct answer here by making the button blink green
        }else   {
            Toast.makeText(BegineerActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// i need to validate wrong answer here by making the button blink red

        }
        if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
            // once user answer the question, we move on to the next one, if any
            updateQuestion();
            updateQuizNumber(mquizNumber);
        } else {

//           
        }


    }



    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Handler that will help you. You can use it like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.textviewAnswer).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_layout));
            Handler handler2 = new Handler();
            handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    findViewById(R.id.textviewAnswer).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white_layout));
                    Handler handler3 = new Handler();
                    handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            findViewById(R.id.textviewAnswer).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_layout));
                        }
                    }, 200);
                }
            }, 200);
```

this code will help you to blink your textview_layout or button for every 200 milliseconds. You can arrange the time in milliseconds and if you want to make more blink animation, you need to write more nested Handler-s

I wish it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

> i want the correct answer(button) to blink green color and the wrong
>   one to blink red color in case the user gets it wrong

You can change your button color like this

```
 if (answer.getText() == mAnswer){
    Toast.makeText(BegineerActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); // change button color to green
 }else{
    // set button background color to red 
 }
```

To know how to blink a button, you may follow this answer

[How to make a Button blink in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43705550/5156075)

Comment: thanks for the answer. but how exactly can i make the green color blink for a set time say 2 seconds before it moves to the next question

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like below

```
    if (answer.getText() == mAnswer){
        Toast.makeText(BegineerActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);// This will change button color to green
animation(); // this will blink button
     }else{
        // set button background color to red 
     }
private void animation(){
Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim.setDuration(200); //This will blink button for 2 seconds
    anim.setStartOffset(20);
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    answer.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Let me know if you need any clarification. Thanks

Comment: the color change and animation work as expected but the color change is permanent. How do i make it appear for a set time say 2 seconds and thereafter revert to its default color?